# Apache camel not fwding all the message to AMQ, if using delay

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to read message from activemq queue "AMQ:ORIGIN" using apache camel. After reading the message need to pass it to two different "AMQ queue's". But condition is following.

1. Message should pass to queue "AMQ:A" Immediately.
2. Message should pass to queue "AMQ:B" After one minute delay.

To Achieve above  i created two routes. In first route i am reading from AMQ queue, and doing multicast to "AMQ:A" and "seda:delay" queue. In second route, i am reading from "seda:delay" queue,  delaying for one minute and then passing to "AMQ:B" queue.

Work fine if pass with 1 or 10 messages to "AMQ:ORIGIN"

If i send 100 messages same time to "AMQ:ORIGIN" queue, then

1. All 100 messages are delivered to "AMQ:A" queue
2. Only 10 or 12 messages are delivered to "AMQ:B" queue. Rest is stuck in route only.

Following are my routes.

```
        <route id="read-origin">
            <from uri="activemq:ORIGIN"/>
            <multicast stopOnException="true">
                <to uri="activemq:A"/>
                <to uri="seda:delay-route"/>
            </multicast>
        </route>

        <route id="delay-route">
            <from uri="seda:delay-route"/>
            <delay asyncDelayed="true">
                <constant>60000</constant>
            </delay>
            <to uri="activemq:B"/>
        </route>
```

Please suggest the changes to achieve above.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be obvious since you delay **every message for 1 minute**.

If you send 100 messages to the `ORIGIN` queue, it takes **100 minutes** until all these messages arrive at queue `B`.

The first message is consumed immediately, and delayed for 1 minute. The second is taken when the first is delivered (assuming 1 consumer on seda queue) and also delayed for one minute and so on...

I assume you want that a message that **already waited for 1 minute in the queue, can be delivered immediately when consumed**.

You can easily reach this making the delay dynamic.

Implement a bean that calculates the difference between the `JMSTimestamp` header (enqueue time) of a message and the current time.

`currentTime - JMSTimestamp` = alreadyWaited

`Your minimal delay - alreadyWaited` = time to wait before delivery (take 0 for negative values of messages that where queued for more than the delay)

Use this difference as value for the delay (I use Java DSL because I know it better).

```
from("seda:delay-route").routeId("delay-route")
    .delay().expression(method(YourDelayCalculationBean.class))
    .to("activemq:B");
```

Like this, if your messages pile up in the queue, they are probably all delivered immediately on consumption because they already waited in the queue for more than 1 minute.

**Addition due to comment**

OK, sorry, I did not spot the `asyncDelayed`.

What the docs say about `asyncDelayed` sounds like what you expect. But according to your comment it sounds like the [Delay EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/delay-eip.html) is no more blocking the consumer, but blocks itself.

So the seda consumer takes a message, hands it over to the Delay and continues to the next message. After 10 messages (10 threads is the default thread pool size of Camel), the Delay is "full" (all threads are blocked in a fixed 1 minute delay).

Therefore the consumer becomes blocked because the Delay can take no more messages. After a minute, the Delay can deliver the first messages and it continues.

That is just wild guessing based on what you write how your route behaves.

Comment: I also thought the same, but my queue is seda queue and i enabled the asyncDelayed="true" . Hence Nth messge should not wait for Nth minute. 

Also messages are not coming evrey 1 minute. It is like 10 messages came after 1 minute. And stopped.

Comment: I have extended my answer with a guess why the routes behaves like this

Comment: Yah it make sense. but once first 10 messages released. then next 10 messages should come after t+2 minutes(if all messages comes at time t). Which is not happening.